# Class validation on response body in .NET WebApi

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I would like to apply class validation on the response body/output of my .NET WebApi in the same way .NET automatically validates the request body using class validation.

```
public class RequestAndResponseDto
{
   [Required]
   public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    Task<RequestAndResponseDto> Post([FromBody] RequestAndResponseDto requestBody)
    {
         return new RequestAndResponseDto();
    }
}
```

I would like an exception to be thrown, because SomeProperty is a required property. The same would go for other validations, such as MinLength etc.

The solution should be applied to all controllers and all methods in the application. How would I achieve this without adding custom logic in each endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply class validation on the response body/output globally across all controllers and methods in your .NET Web API, you can create and register an action filter that performs model validation on the action result. This approach allows you to reuse the validation logic without modifying each endpoint individually.

Here's how you can achieve this:

1. Create a Custom Action Filter for Response Validation

---

First, create a custom action filter that checks if the action result is of the type that needs validation (e.g., your DTOs) and then performs the validation using the Validator class.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class ValidateResponseAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
        {
            var result = objectResult.Value;
            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(result, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
            var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

            bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(result, validationContext, validationResults, true);

            if (!isValid)
            {
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(validationResults);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Register the Custom Action Filter Globally

---

Next, you need to register this action filter globally so it's applied to all controllers and actions. You can do this in the Startup.cs or wherever you configure services in your application.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new ValidateResponseAttribute()); // Register the filter globally
    });
    // Other service configurations...
}
```

This setup ensures that your response DTOs are validated just like your request DTOs. If the validation fails, a BadRequest response is returned with the validation errors.
Note: This approach validates the response before it's sent back to the client. It's important to ensure that your application logic correctly handles cases where the response data might not pass validation, as this could indicate a flaw in your application's data handling or business logic.

Comment: While applying global response validation in your .NET Web API using a custom action filter can enhance the consistency and reliability of your API responses, there are several considerations and potential downsides to be aware of:
1. Performance Overhead: Validation introduces additional processing for every response. For high-throughput APIs, this could impact performance. It's important to benchmark and understand the performance implications for your specific use case.

Comment: 2. Unexpected Behavior: Automatically validating responses might lead to unexpected behavior if your application logic intentionally returns responses that don't conform to the validation rules under certain conditions. This could result in errors being returned to clients in situations where the API's business logic intended a different outcome.

Comment: 3. Error Handling Complexity: Implementing global response validation means that your controllers and services need to be designed with the expectation that responses could be rejected due to validation failures. This could complicate error handling logic, especially if different parts of your application need to handle validation failures in different ways.

Comment: 4. Validation Logic Duplication: If your application already performs validation at the business logic or service layer, adding an additional layer of validation at the response level might result in duplication of validation logic. This can make the application harder to maintain and increase the risk of inconsistencies between different validation layers.

Comment: 5. Global vs. Granular Control: Applying validation globally means it affects all controllers and actions. While this ensures consistency, it might not be desirable for all endpoints. Some endpoints might require different validation rules or no validation at all. You'll need to implement additional logic to selectively apply validation where it's actually needed.

Comment: 6. Complex Object Graphs: For complex object graphs, the default validation might not be sufficient or might lead to incomplete validation. Custom validators or additional validation logic might be necessary to fully validate complex nested objects or collections.

Comment: 7. Client-Side Implications: Clients consuming your API need to be prepared to handle validation error responses. This means that client-side error handling and user feedback mechanisms must be designed to interpret and present validation errors in a user-friendly manner.

Comment: To mitigate these downsides, it's important to carefully design your validation strategy. Consider where validation should be applied (globally vs. selectively), how to handle complex validation scenarios, and how to ensure that validation does not introduce unintended side effects in your application's behavior. Testing and documentation also become crucial to ensure that the API's behavior aligns with expectations and that clients can correctly handle validation errors.

Comment: Did you use generative AI like ChatGPT to write this answer and the accompanying comments?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this in your controller endpoint if you want to validate it on an endpoint level.

```html
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<RequestAndResponseDto>> Post([FromBody] RequestAndResponseDto requestBody)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return UnprocessableEntity(ModelState);
    }
    return new RequestAndResponseDto();
}
```

[image: Error response]

```html
public class RequestAndResponseDto
{
    [MinLength(1)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "some error")]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

or you could also add it to a middleware:

```html
public class ModelValidationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<ModelValidationMiddleware> _logger;

    public ModelValidationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ModelValidationMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api")) // Assuming API endpoints for validation
        {
            // Read request body
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            // Deserialize request body into model
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestAndResponseDto>(requestBody);

            // Validate model using data annotations
            var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(model, new ValidationContext(model), validationResults, true);

            if (!isValid)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("Model validation failed.");

                // Collect validation errors
                var errors = new List<string>();
                foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
                {
                    foreach (var memberName in validationResult.MemberNames)
                    {
                        errors.Add($"{memberName}: {validationResult.ErrorMessage}");
                    }
                }

                // Return validation errors in the response
                var errorResponse = new { Errors = errors };
                var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errorResponse);

                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(jsonResponse);
                return;
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Remember to add the middleware to the App:

```html
builder.UseMiddleware<ModelValidationMiddleware>()
```